# Como carregar dados no CSV no oracle SEM SQL Loader?

Tags: java, oracle, csv, batch

Os dados de uma tabela foram exportados em um arquivo CSV e gostaria de importá-lo para uma tabela no banco Oracle. Porém preciso que seja sem o comando sqlldr. Pois essa carga será feita no Java, e tenho restrições de uso do SQL Loader aplicadas pela equipe de banco de dados.

Considere que este CSV pode possuir milhões de registros!

Acredito que a opção de Tabela Externa não atenderia, porque estou trabalhando com milhões de registros.

Comment: Alguma coisa precisa interpretar o CSV, precisa coloca-los em um INSERT e roda-los no banco. Por exemplo: você pode fazer um programa para fazer isso, você pode montar os inserts no Excel e roda-los no SQL-Plus e por ai vai. Dado ao montante de linhas o SQLDR seria a melhor opção

Comment: Você criar  Classes Java para ler este arquivo , existem sites com exemplo para isto em Java e PLSQL  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html

Answer (score 1):

O banco de dados Oracle possui uma funcionalidade denominada ORACLE_LOADER, onde não é feito import do arquivo para uma tabela do banco de dados. É criada uma tabela que aponta para um arquivo CSV (na verdade não precisa ser um arquivo no formato .CSV), assim, você pode possuir um processo que exclusivamente efetua carga no arquivo sem a necessidade de destruir e construir o objeto table novamente.
Segue exemplo de código utilizando o ORACLE_LOADER:

```
    CREATE TABLE DE_PARA_PECAS
(
CD_PRODUTO_ANTERIOR  varchar2(20),
CD_PRODUTO_NOVO      varchar2(20),
VL_CUSTO             varchar2(20)
)
ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL
  (  TYPE ORACLE_LOADER
     DEFAULT DIRECTORY NFE
     ACCESS PARAMETERS 
       ( records delimited  by newline
        fields  terminated by ';'
        missing field values are null
             )
     LOCATION (NFE:'de_para_pecas.csv')
  )
REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED
NOPARALLEL
NOMONITORING;
```

Segue link para acessar o manual da Oracle que apresenta esta feature:
[ORACLE_LOADER_HELP_CENTER](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10825/et_params.htm)